# are audio output levels consistent across computers?

Tags: audio

I wasn't able to find this information online. I want to know if the output audio volume from a typical laptop computer would be the same across different computers for a given volume level (assume whatever software is being used delivers the same audio file at the same volume), and, if not, what are the factors that affect it. For example, would 50% volume on my system result in the same output dB as on another laptop with the volume bar set to 50%? Would the change in the audio output level be consistent across systems with the same change in adjusting the volume? I'm not concerned about any device on which the audio will be delivered to; only the output from the computer.

If the answer is no to both questions, is there a way to 'standardize' the output audio level?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the question about consistent change in the audio output level? For example assume that 40% volume on one computer results in the same loudness as 100% on a different one. How would you measure if the change is consistent? Don't use comments to answer, [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** The audio output volume may be very different on different computers.

I have access to different laptop models where in one case I use 100% volume and it is still difficult to hear while on the other model 50% volume is sufficient and louder than 50% on the other one.

This is affected by all hardware involved with the analog part of the audio output, e.g. audio interface chip, amplifiers and speakers (integrated in the laptop by the manufacturer).